# Pyspark combineByKey list of tuples and count

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been having difficulty combining keyed tuples of two floats in an rdd into a list of theses keyed tuples into a list and the count of each, for each key.  I am using rdd. combineByKey to do this.  If I pass values to the three lambda’s outside of combineByKey I get the results I would expect, a key and a tuple of list of tuples and the count.  But, when I do this with combineByKey, I get a key and a tuple of list of one constant value and the count.  What may I be missing here?  I captured the REPL output below to illustrate.

```
j = jnd.take(2)
```

`j`:

```
[[u'14225532965000', (0.2072, 82777.0)], [u'14217732824000', (0.20361902000000001, 77271.0)]]
creCmb = (lambda v: ([v[1]], 1))
mrgVal = (lambda x, v: (x[0]+[v[1]], x[1]+1))
mrgCmb = (lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]))
x = creCmb(j[0])
```

`x`:

```
([(0.2072, 82777.0)], 1) 
m = mrgVal(x, j[1])
```

`m`:

```
([(0.2072, 82777.0), (0.20361902000000001, 77271.0)], 2) 
r = mrgCmb(m, m)
```

`r`:

```
([(0.2072, 82777.0), (0.20361902000000001, 77271.0), (0.2072, 82777.0), (0.20361902000000001, 77271.0)], 4) 
cmb = jnd.combineByKey(creCmb, mrgVal, mrgCmb) 
cmb.count() 
4513
cmb.take(1)
[(u'14225532026000', ([56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, ...
... 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0, 56917.0], 741))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

combineByKey only calls the functions provided to it on the *values* of each row. In `creCmb` and `mrgVal`, when you use `v[1]` instead of just `v`, you only keep the second element of each value tuple, resulting in a list of single elements in the end. In your test, you call `creCmb` on a key-value pair instead of just a value tuple, which is why the test output is correct but the combineByKey output is not.

To fix this, simply remove the `[1]` indexing from both `creCmb` and `mrgVal`:

```py
creCmb = (lambda v: ([v], 1))
mrgVal = (lambda x, v: (x[0]+[v], x[1]+1))
```

Comment: I removed the indexing from creCmb, and also mrgVal, it would have the same issue.  I now get a list of tuples of two doubles and a count, but the two double tuples are all the same. [(u'14225532026000', ([(0.19018832999999999, 56917.0), (0.19018832999999999, 56917.0), ... (0.19018832999999999, 56917.0), (0.19018832999999999, 56917.0)], 741))]

Comment: Your solution worked great.  After fixing the lambdas I was able to find a problem with my data logic that.  Thank you.